# Journey rejected contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I have a list of rejected contacts in one of my running journeys.

I see the **status is 'Failed'** but I need to know why. I ran the preview of the email for those contacts and worked well so I don't know where is the problem.

They also apply to the entry criteria and all the fields and values of the data extension that are used in the journey are correct.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the Subscriber Status (in All Subscribers) for each of the failed records? Have you had records successfully enter the Journey, or do they all fail?

Comment: They don't exist as Subscribers, the failed. I already add the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Fromero - So the failed records do not exist (as contacts) in All Subscribers. Can you confirm the data for these records is eligible to be sent an email (Valid SubscriberKey/EmailAddress) AND the EmailAddress provided is not found in your Suppression/Exclusion list. Are the recipient email addresses "info@..." or "admin@..."?

Comment: Yes, 99% of the email addresses are "info@" or "mail@". There are not any suppression/exclusion lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce Marketing Cloud has a default setting that prevents the sending of emails to "generic addresses", such as admin@, info@ and so on.

This is likely the reason why these addresses have failed to enter the Journey.

Reference: [List Detective](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316767&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: thanks! But I don't see the 'List Detective for Domain' tab in the account, is it called in a different way?

Comment: As far as I know, the most comprehensive (and open to contributions) overview for what is filtered out by list detective can be found on github:

https://github.com/eliotharper/role-based-email-addresses/blob/master/index.js

hint: a lot

Comment: The article (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315115&type=1&mode=1) suggests contacting Support to get your enterprise list amended.

Comment: Does List Detective functionality have to be enabled by support? I don't see it in the tool.

Answer (score 4):

info@ and mail@ are called "Role-based emails".

Because role-based and reserved email addresses often represent multiple recipients, they generate many spam complaints. To prevent unnecessary spam complaints, List Detective restricts these email addresses on imports and doesn’t send email to reserved email addresses.

You can use Custom List Detective to overcome this:

> CLD can also be used to ALLOW sending to users or domains blocked by
>   the system due to the List Detective feature. List Detective by
>   default includes a wide array of common rule/role based email
>   addresses such as info@, support@, admin@ for example, as well as
>   explicit words and spam like names such as @spam.

See here for more details:

[Use Custom List Detective to restrict sending to addresses or domains in Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316767&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: but we are talking about Marketing Cloud, does it work the same way?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same way - you can reach out to Support and ask them to disable it in your account for some of the email addresses.

Answer (score -2):

In Automation Studio it is possible to create a Data Extract of the type: Tracking Extract. The Tracking Extract creates a zip-file as output. In the Tracking Extract you can select the Not Sents. After running the automation (2 steps: 1 - Data Extract; 2 - File Transfer (Move from Safehouse to the Enhanced FTP)), the extract can be checked for the reason why the emails were not sent.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_notsent.htm&type=5